# FOUND_ROWS() keeps returning 0

Tags: php, select, count

```
$result = $db_con->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM users LIMIT 0,10");

$count_result = $db_con->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as totalcount");
$row = $count_result->fetch_assoc();
$total = $row['totalcount'];
```

$total keeps returning 0 even though the $result contains all the user rows in it.

```
ini_set("mysql.trace_mode", "0");
```

I found out about this setting via searching a similar Q on here, but it did not resolve my issue.

When I use the 2 select statements in my MySQL client it always outputs the right count. Just can't seem to figure out how to get it working on my php page.

PHP Version: 5.2.5 build 6
MySQL Version: 5.1.30

Note: The code I provided here is not being used on my actual project, however, it does exemplify the problem I am having with not being able to retrieve the total count. This code, from what I've read about found_rows(), should work but it doesn't.

Comment: @Seth : did you try adding the LIMIT clause?

Comment: ini_set("mysql.trace_mode", "0"); solve my problem. Thanks for question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On php.net I found someone with maybe the same problem. He is speaking of a race condition that could occur: [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php#85654). Basically he solves this problem by temporary locking the table at the cost of slowing things down.

Comment: I found that post when I was googling. I guess I'll go back to using count(*).

Answer (score 1):

**`LIMIT` is required to make found_rows() work correctly**

Add a LIMIT to the end of your query, ie.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM users LIMIT 0,10;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

`FOUND_ROWS()` -- For a SELECT with a LIMIT clause, the number of rows that would be returned were there no LIMIT clause

Comment: Even with the limit clause I get 0 for totalcount.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure what database library you're using but it looks like you are trying to count the number of rows in a select statement in php from a mysql database.

Have you tried seeing if it works with the built in mysql database functions in php?

```
$count_result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as totalcount FROM users");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($count_result);

$total = $row['totalcount'];
```

Comment: -1 : does not answer the original question about LIMIT, and FOUND_ROWS()