# Two seemingly identical queries returning different results when using count (pagination)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am running two queries to my database for pagination reasons. As such, each query is nearly identical. My COUNT(*) query is not returning the number of results that the non-count query is. I'm baffled as to why this is the case. The queries are below.

```
SELECT p.host_id, p.rating_support, p.rating_tech, MAX(p.rating_overall) AS rating_overall, p.publish_rating, h.name, prices.price, prices.term_duration
FROM plans p
INNER JOIN hosts AS h ON h.id = p.host_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT plan_id, price, term_duration FROM prices WHERE price > 0 AND price < 50 AND term_duration = 1) prices ON prices.plan_id = p.id
WHERE p.published = 1 AND h.published = 1
GROUP BY p.host_id
ORDER BY rating_overall desc LIMIT 0, 12

SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM plans p
INNER JOIN hosts AS h ON h.id = p.host_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT plan_id, price, term_duration FROM prices WHERE price > 0 AND price < 50 AND term_duration = 1) prices ON prices.plan_id = p.id
WHERE p.published = 1 AND h.published = 1
GROUP BY p.host_id
```

I'm not an expert at MySQL. Besides the count not providing the correct number of results, the non-count query works perfectly.

Any light on this problem would be great.

Comment: I see that you have a LIMIT on your first query but not on the second. This might be limiting results that you want to consider.

Comment: Hello @Andrew, yes the first query must limit the results for pagination reasons. For instance, the first page will display up to 12 results. The second page will display another 12 results, using the limit to offset. The second query should not be limited as we need to know the full number of results to determine how many pages we'll have. My issues is, the first query returns 6 results and the second query COUNT(*) returns 3. How can this happen?

Comment: I'd suspect it's the MAX that's not in the count query.  That will eliminate records that count does not.

Comment: Hello @Jesse, the query with MAX(p.rating_overall) returns 6 records. The COUNT(*) query returns a count of 3. In this case, the query with MAX() returns more than the COUNT(*) query. If it was the other way around, I'd believe you were on to something. ;) Feel free to elaborate if I didn't understand your comment. Thanks!

Comment: I also think the MAX() is the culprit - can you post the the results of explain extended <query>; show warnings; to see what the query plan is and what query mysql is actually executing. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html

Comment: I've been playing with the query in phpMyAdmin and I noticed that the `COUNT(*)` query is returning multiple rows (is this due to the joins?). In PHP, I returned the first result expecting it to be the only result, this is why my returned count is wrong. Is there a way I can change my `COUNT(*)` query to count the returned rows rather than the associated joined data? If I change `COUNT(*)` to `h.id` and remove my `GROUP BY`, I receive something like: 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, etc. Add `GROUP BY`, I get 1, 2, 3, etc. Add `COUNT(h.id)` and I get 4, 10, 7, 2 instead of the count of rows

Comment: I can solve my problem by using php `count()` on the returned array. I merely am interested if there is a way to structure the query a little different to return what I want. Do you still need the explain? If I select 'Explain SQL' in phpMyAdmin, will that provide you the information you need? Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: 'Explain SQL' in phpMyAdmin does not give enough info - that just gives the query plan - Ideally it would be nice to see the actual query mysql is executing. Seems odd the count(*) returns more than 1 row - its possible there is some Cartesian multiplication happening.

Comment: @AdrianCornish - It's not strange at all.  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY x` will return one row per distinct value of x, and report how many rows of data are aggregated together for each distinct value of x.  It's just like `SELECT x, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY x`.  So, if the first query give 6 rows, the second query should give 6 rows too, and the results be how many rows of data have been aggregated together per distinct value of p.host_id.

Comment: @Akaishen - Your `COUNT(*)` query has `GROUP BY p.host_id`.  This means `return one row per distinct value of p.host id`.  This is why *both* queries return 6 rows.  Also, `COUNT(*)` tells you how many rows were aggregated together *(by the GROUP BY)* to form that one output row.  `COUNT(distinct p.host_id)` instead tells you how many distinct values of p.host_id exist in that one output row.  So, either use `COUNT(distinct p.host_id`) ***and*** remove the `GROUP BY`, or do what @biziclop suggests.  Use a nested query to count the rows in the results, rather than counting the rows in the input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of Dems' comment ([hunt down and upvote him](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/dems?tab=answers) somewhere :), I created this query. Notice that I removed the subquery, because it seemed unnecessary:

```
SELECT
  COUNT( DISTINCT p.host_id )
FROM       plans p
INNER JOIN hosts h ON h.id = p.host_id
INNER JOIN prices  ON prices.plan_id = p.id
                  AND prices.price > 0
                  AND prices.price < 50
                  AND prices.term_duration = 1
WHERE p.published = 1
  AND h.published = 1
```

---

My original answer:

To get the number of total row, you have to wrap the `GROUP BY` query into an outer `SELECT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT NULL -- we are just counting, so we need no actual data -> a bit faster
  FROM       plans p
  INNER JOIN hosts h ON h.id = p.host_id
  INNER JOIN prices  ON prices.plan_id = p.id
                    AND prices.price > 0
                    AND prices.price < 50
                    AND prices.term_duration = 1
  WHERE p.published = 1
    AND h.published = 1
  GROUP BY p.host_id
) AS all_rows_without_data
```

Or you could use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` + `FOUND_ROWS()`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

> A SELECT statement may include a LIMIT clause to restrict the number
>   of rows the server returns to the client. In some cases, it is
>   desirable to know how many rows the statement would have returned
>   without the LIMIT, but without running the statement again. To obtain
>   this row count, include a SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in the SELECT
>   statement, and then invoke FOUND_ROWS() afterward:

First, simply select the required rows, but add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  p.host_id, p.rating_support, p.rating_tech,
  MAX(p.rating_overall) AS rating_overall,
  p.publish_rating, h.name, prices.price, prices.term_duration
FROM       plans p
INNER JOIN hosts AS h ON h.id = p.host_id
INNER JOIN prices  ON prices.plan_id = p.id
                  AND prices.price > 0
                  AND prices.price < 50
                  AND prices.term_duration = 1
WHERE p.published = 1 AND h.published = 1
GROUP BY p.host_id
ORDER BY rating_overall desc
LIMIT 0, 12;
```

Second, get the number of rows that would have been returned if there weren't a `LIMIT` statement in the first query:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

*Update*: `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` + `FOUND_ROWS()` doesn't seem very reliable, always returs zero for unknown reason (not just me: [FOUND_ROWS() keeps returning 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020745/found-rows-keeps-returning-0) ):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7304d/8

Comment: Or...  As the original query is `SELECT z, a, b, c FROM y GROUP BY z` it can be changed to `SELECT COUNT(distinct z) FROM y` with no GROUP BY at all.

Comment: Thanks, true! If you create an answer from it, i will delete my own.

Comment: Mine is an alternative and yours is a valid answer.  I don't want you to delete it, so I'm not going to post my answer.  But I'd be happy for you to *add* it to your own :)  *[One reason to use your version is for testing - the less alterations you make to a query to test it the better.  My suggestion could be a tiny bit quicker, and slightly more concise, but yours ensures that the original query has been tested, rather than a similar query; and similar means introducing human error.]*

Comment: Thank you everyone for clearly explaining what was happening. I've learned a lot from your posts and will use the COUNT(DISTINCT p.host_id) to get the correct count of rows. I have done some reading on SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and determined that it wasn't reliable enough to use. Nonetheless, I chose this answer because it was the most complete, providing the most options for a solution. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

The result of your second query would return the same number of rows, but the first row won't give you back the total.

The results would give the count for each group per row:

```
3
5
1
6
etc.
etc.
```

To get the result into one row, use `COUNT(DISTINCT p.host_id)` or `array_sum()` in PHP on the full result set.

Comment: It's certainly -not- `just` drop the GROUP by.  In your example that would return `3+5+1+6+etc+etc`.  If the OP drops the `GROUP BY` the OP *must* use `COUNT(distinct p.host_id)` as well.  See my comments above.

Comment: Thanks @Jack for your post. It's the answer I was looking for though is included with biziclop's answer. I'll give you an up-vote for the help though. :)